# WAMPSERVER virtual host not working and black hat error log messages

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

For some reason my virtual host has stopped working after installing the windows 8.1 preview which hasn't changed any files, I have check all of the settings/host file and they are still the same.

Additionally I just checked my error log and I have some strange messages with the w00tw00t black hat  and I am not sure how serious it is and what is needed to prevent it as I only use the wampserver for creating and testing so I haven't really considered security that much on it. See the messages below:

```
[Fri Jul 05 10:46:50.530891 2013] [core:error] [pid 2276:tid 1644] [client 112.216.56.58:41021] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET <title>phpMyAdmin HTTP/1.1
[Fri Jul 05 10:47:35.955591 2013] [core:error] [pid 2276:tid 1636] [client 112.216.56.58:37237] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET <title>phpMyAdmin HTTP/1.1
[Fri Jul 05 10:48:40.849824 2013] [core:error] [pid 2276:tid 1636] [client 112.216.56.58:35299] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET <title>phpMyAdmin HTTP/1.1
[Fri Jul 05 19:19:20.762245 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1644] [client 58.218.199.250:2678] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/ip.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Jul 06 01:01:31.057542 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1644] [client 58.218.199.250:3488] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/judge.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Jul 06 18:31:27.013514 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1636] [client 58.218.199.250:1072] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/ip.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Jul 07 00:18:23.526305 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1636] [client 58.218.199.250:3124] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/judge.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Jul 07 06:06:29.065962 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1636] [client 58.218.199.250:1055] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/judge.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Jul 07 14:56:16.247827 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1608] [client 58.218.199.250:2531] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/ip.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Jul 07 17:51:47.664564 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1608] [client 58.218.199.250:1083] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/judge.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jul 08 05:29:18.812115 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1632] [client 58.218.199.250:2121] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/proxyheader.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jul 08 08:24:24.184430 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1632] [client 58.218.199.250:2312] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/proxyheader.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jul 08 10:22:43.460832 2013] [core:error] [pid 2276:tid 1632] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client 219.142.74.32:36211] AH00127: Cannot map GET /w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:) HTTP/1.1 to file
[Mon Jul 08 17:13:02.492876 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1608] [client 58.218.199.250:4642] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/aop0igj.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Jul 09 19:40:41.125664 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1636] [client 58.218.199.250:1686] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/proxyheader.php' not found or unable to stat
[Wed Jul 10 01:29:54.474140 2013] [:error] [pid 2276:tid 1636] [client 58.218.199.250:3712] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/judge.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jul 11 12:48:56.141853 2013] [:error] [pid 4272:tid 1628] [client 58.218.199.250:1354] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/proxyheader.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jul 11 15:49:21.114210 2013] [:error] [pid 4272:tid 1628] [client 58.218.199.250:3950] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/aop0igj.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jul 11 19:52:48.727956 2013] [core:error] [pid 4272:tid 1600] [client 199.19.107.6:52897] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET <title>phpMyAdmin HTTP/1.1
[Thu Jul 11 19:52:50.415469 2013] [core:error] [pid 4272:tid 1636] [client 199.19.107.6:54153] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET  HTTP/1.1
[Fri Jul 12 21:26:57.610483 2013] [core:error] [pid 4272:tid 1600] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client 202.104.192.164:33167] AH00127: Cannot map GET /w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:) HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Jul 13 05:37:22.188676 2013] [core:error] [pid 4272:tid 1636] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client 85.249.4.47:56578] AH00127: Cannot map GET /w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:) HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Jul 13 20:24:14.463941 2013] [:error] [pid 4272:tid 1600] [client 58.218.199.250:2994] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/proxyheader.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Jul 13 23:26:20.631467 2013] [:error] [pid 4272:tid 1600] [client 58.218.199.250:2639] script 'C:/wamp/www/domain/proxyheader.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: i think the blackhat requests have nothing to do with your problem. read this: http://support.scalr.net/discussions/questions/1841-should-i-be-worried-about-w00tw00tatblackhatsromaniananti-sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it like this
1. click on the red icon in the system tray

1. Select the menu apache/srvice/install service
2. then select MySql/service/install service

(Now it works)

Comment: you can add images for answer...its better approch

Answer (score 0):

My friend.

I got a lot of problems with WampServer and i have solved all my problems when i have found a program called UwAmp.

Its not too much known, but when i got this... i do never get more problems with local servers.

Its fantastic.

Take a look, i believe that you will like it too much.

http://www.uwamp.com/en/

That have a virtual hosts editor, cpu monitor, and a lot more tools. Very easy to use, dont need to install, you can put in any location and its works without need any work of config.

Comment: Not relevant to the actual issue.

Comment: Ok, -1 that... still using the trash wampserver =(
Im very happy with my uwamp =)

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume that you have port forwarded your router to allow access from the `big bad internet`, because it looks like you are being probed by some hackers.

They are just trying to find if you have any known compromised code on your site. There is not much you can do to stop it. This is why live servers are better off on proper hosted environments professionally maintained and managed.